# Matching values between two Python dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

`dictGroupMembers` is a dictionary with keys representing course codes, with values containing a list of student IDs who are enrolled in that course.

`dictCourseMembers` is a dictionary which contains a key of student name, and a value of that student' ID.

I am trying to create a list or dictionary of course codes, along with the names of students who are enrolled in those courses.

My current code is as follows:

```
dictGroupMembers= {11784: [264, 265, 266], 11794: [], 11795: [], 11796: [], 11834: []}
dictCourseMembers= {'Student, Dummy01': '265', 'Student, Dummy02': '264', 'Student, Dummy03': '266', 'TestStudent, Van de, Eddy': '49076'}

list=[]
for i in dictGroupMembers.values():
    for j in dictCourseMembers.values():
        for b in j:
            if i==b:
              list[i].append
print(list)
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: So the task is?

Comment: I am trying to figure out which students are enrolled in which course? The code i generated is not working properly.

Comment: @Abdullah Inverse the keys and values of the 2nd dictionary and use a dictionary comprehension to recreate the poorly named `listA`. Watch out for data types; you seem to be mixing strings and integers.

Comment: @Abdullah You also shouldn't be using list as a name for a variable, considering it is a predefined function.

Comment: I did inverse the keys, how ever the output of the new List is still empty. I am very new to python by the way.

Comment: Your main errors are: iterating `for b in j` and `j` is `string`. comparing `i` (a list) and `b` (a string). initiating `list` as list and not as dictionary

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ListA= {11784: [264, 265, 266], 11794: [264], 11795: [264,266], 11796: [265,266], 11834: [265,264]}
ListB= {'Student, Dummy01': '265', 'Student, Dummy02': '264', 'Student, Dummy03': '266', 'TestStudent, Van de, Eddy': '49076'}

dict1={}

for student_id in ListB.values():
    subject_list=[]
    for subject,student_list in ListA.items():
        for student in student_list:
            if student_id==str(student):
                subject_list.append(subject)
    dict1[student_id]=subject_list

print(dict1)
```

I hope this will give you a better output with student id and each subject taken

output:

```
{'265': [11784, 11796, 11834], '264': [11784, 11794, 11795, 11834], '266': [11784, 11795, 11796], '49076': []}
```

Note: I have modified the ListA that you provided to make sure the algo works and it works.

Comment: It almost solved it, I am trying to print the name of the students aswell next to the student iD. Then it will solve the problem definitely

Comment: Am i allowed to pass an extra argument as Name in to the dictionary ?

Comment: Yes definitely, just read out the keys in ListB and then you can append it to the list finally and then point the dictionary key at it.